# Separate border with collapsed border model

Tags: html, css

I would like to somehow combine the "separate" and "collapse" `border-collapse` properties. Or rather, I want to use the collapse model, but add some separation between two specific cells/columns, like this:

```
=================
A    B     C    D
   ----- -----
   b1 b2 c1 c2
-----------------
1  2  3  4  5   6
11 12 13 14 15 16
21 22 23 24 25 26
=================
```

Note that the bottom lines of `B` and `C` should not touch, to convey that `b1` and `b2` belong to `B`, and `c1` and `c2` belong to `C`.

I have an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/f1h87wpn/

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; border: black solid; border-width: 2px 0; border-spacing: 0.5em; }
tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(2) { border-bottom: black solid 1px; }
tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(3) { border-bottom: black solid 1px; }
tr:nth-of-type(2) { border-bottom: black solid 1px; }
td { text-align: center }
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>A</td><td colspan="2">B</td><td colspan="2">C</td><td>D</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>b1</td><td>b2</td><td>c1</td><td>cd</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td></tr>
<tr><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td><td>24</td><td>25</td><td>26</td></tr>
</table>
```

and of course, with this the borders touch. If I change `border-collapse` to `separate`, this border looks fine, but the line below the second row disappears (as expected). Can anyone think of any trick to get the result I'm after? I cannot change the HTML, since it's machine-generated, so adding a `div` with margin in the `B` and `C` cells is not a possibility.

Comment: If the code is machine generated, are you able to manipulate the code with JavaScript?

Comment: @pbaldauf Yes, I can do that, but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: Ok thats a tough question. I think you can achieve the desired result if you make use of *CSS pseudo elements* and place a div with white background where you want to have the gap.

Comment: a `border-image` could do the trick, but IE only supports it in the newest version...

Comment: Is the number of b and c elements dynamic? Or will it always be 2? If it's dynamic you'll need to use javascript anyway

Comment: @ZachSaucier There may be any number of columns, and they may be placed anywhere, but I'm appling the formatting to each table separately (using `#id` selectors), so, within each table, it is static.

Answer (score 1):

This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f1h87wpn/3/) should do the trick. (Tested on FF 33)

Mainly I have added a **pseudo-Element** for a horizontal row like this:

```
tr:nth-of-type(3) { 
    position: relative; 
}
tr:nth-of-type(3)::after { 
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And also set `border-width` at least **3px** if you want a `border-style: double`:

```
border-top: black double 3px;
```

Comment: Nice. The only nitpick is that the line does not extend all the way to the table edges (try with `border-spacing: 1em`), but I guess I can live with that. It might also break in unexpected ways, so maybe I will resort to some other kind of formatting after all.

Comment: If you have `border-spacing: 1em` on table you could change the `width` and position-left property in the `after`-pseudo element like http://jsfiddle.net/f1h87wpn/4/

Comment: Or, if available, using `calc`: `left: -1em; width: calc( 100% + 2em );` ;)

Comment: While this solution works (at least in FF32), it has an undesired side effect: an additional border-spacing is added at the right of the table, this is apparently due to the `::after` pseudo-element. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ukakue5c/ Note how the right border space is thicker and the red line extends a bit too much to the right. Can this be fixed? Is it a FF bug?

Comment: Why don't you use the `width: 100% /*fallback*/; width: calc( 100% - 5px )`? See http://jsfiddle.net/ukakue5c/1/

Comment: It helps for the line, but not for the border separation